# Why using never type as array indexer returns union of types of array values

Tags: typescript

```
type T<A> = A[never];

const tuple = ['1', '2'] as const

const array = ['1', '2']

type UninType = T<typeof tuple> // "1" | "2"

type StringType = T<typeof array> // string
```

Why is it done this way, what's the point of this behavior

Comment: oh wow I love this question; stay tuned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

This behavior is just an unintended consequence of how [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) were implemented.  It was [brought up at some point](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22787#issuecomment-376345939) that `T[never]` should be `never` no matter what `T` is; this was [partially fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22787); for `T` with no [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

The fix for index signatures was put off because at the time it would have broken other things, and having `T[never]` resolve to the index signature type was accidentally preventing another problem from showing up.  Nowadays it probably would be fine to implement the full fix, but I guess nobody ever got around to it, probably because it's not really a critical issue.  You might want to open a new [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) asking for this to be addressed, if you care a lot.

---

Long answer:

If you look at [microsoft/TypeScript#11929](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11929), the pull request that implemented indexed access types, it describes the (then) process for determining the type `T[K]`:

> - If `K` is a type assignable to `number` and `T` contains a numeric index signature, `T[K]` is the type of that numeric index signature.
> - If `K` is a type assignable to `string` and `T` contains a string index signature, `T[K]` is the type of that string index signature.

In your case, since array and tuple types have a numeric index signature, and since [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is [assignable to every type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53540282/why-is-never-assignable-to-every-type), then indexing into an array or tuple type with `never` will yield the type of the numeric index signature.

That's consistent with your results anyway.

---

Now at some point people noticed that indexing into a type like `{a: string}` with `never` was resulting in `any` and erroring out.  This was not desirable; it seems that you should be able to index with `never` and the result should also be `never`, like this:

```
type SomeObj = {a: string}[never]
// type SomeObj = never
```

So this was filed as an issue in [microsoft/TypeScript#22042](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22042) and it was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22787](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22787).  (which is why the above `SomeObj` is `never` and not `any`).

In the comments on that fix, someone [noted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22787#issuecomment-375941408) that:

> this change only affects types with no index signature. So for example:
>
> - `{[x: string]: boolean}[never]` is `boolean` (unchanged behaviour)
> - `{foo: boolean}[never]` is `never` (new behaviour, previously was an error)
>
> With that qualification, this is a non-breaking change because it only affects cases that are currently errors.

One of the TS team then [replies](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22787#issuecomment-376335764) that

> After discussing it in person with [**@ahejlsberg**](https://github.com/ahejlsberg), we didn't like the fact that `({ [n: number]: boolean})[never]` is inconsistent: it's not `never` like everything else...

but they couldn't fix it.  At the time, `keyof ({[n: number]: boolean})` was `never` instead of `number`.  I think we can all agree that if `XXX` is `{[n: number]: boolean}`, then we want `XXX[keyof XXX]` to be `boolean`.  But since `keyof XXX` was `never`, then this sort of forced them to have `XXX[never]` also be `boolean` and not `never`.  They couldn't fix it without breaking something that was accidentally working.

Since then, [TypeScript 2.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types) introduced a change to allow `number` and `symbol` types to come out of `keyof`, implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#23592](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592).  So now we have the right behavior:

```
type KeyofNumericIdxSig = keyof { [x: number]: boolean }
// type KeyofNumericIdxSig = number
```

But at the time microsoft/TypeScript#22787 was implemented, this had not been done.  And so the language architect @ahejlsberg himself [said](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22787#issuecomment-376345939):

> [This PR] moves us closer to where we eventually want to be, i.e. that `T[never]` is always `never` regardless of `T`. Longer term, if and when we fix `keyof { [x: number]: T }` to produce `numeric-string` (or whatever we call it) instead of `never`, we can then also change `{ [x: number]: T }[never]` to be `never`.

But it looks like they never came back and completed this.

---

So there you are.  It's possible that if someone were to open a feature request issue linking to both microsoft/TypeScript#22787 and microsoft/TypeScript#23592 and pointing to [this comment in particular](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22787#issuecomment-376345939), they would say "oh gee, yeah we never did that" and implement it.  Or they might say "oh yeah we tried that and it did bad things elsewhere."  Or even "we don't want to worry too much about this unless a lot more people complain about it".  I can't really predict which.

Comment: Your knowledge is impressive