# Why do we use square brackets `[]` in conditionals?

Tags: typescript, types

In this example:

```
type Action<T extends string, P = never> = {
  type: T;
} & ([P] extends [never]
  ? {}
  : {
      payload: P;
    });
```

Why do we need square brackets around conditional `[P] extends [never]` and what is the difference if we don't use it like this `P extends never`?

I understand what this type doing, just can't find explanation on why do we actually need square brackets and why it doesn't work without them.

EDIT:
Let me try with more simple example:

```
type GetTest<T = never> = [T] extends [never] ? string : number;

type Test = GetTest; // type Test = string;
```

Here is `type Test = string` as expected.
But what I didn't get is what happen with condition when we don't have square brackets, we doesn't get `string` but we don't get a `number` too, instead we get `type Test = never`

```
type GetTest<T = never> = T extends never ? string : number;

type Test = GetTest; // type Test = never
```

Comment: `[T]` describes a tuple with a single element of type `T` such as `[never]`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think OP gets that and is asking why you need to wrap it in a tuple in the first place.

Comment: @JaredSmith does he in fact need to do that?

Comment: @jcalz I look into distributive conditional types, thanks for that. Still I do not understand, for example if we doesn't use square brackets: 
```
type Action<T extends string, P = never> = {
  type: T;
} & (P extends never
  ? {}
  : {
      payload: P;
    });

type CounterAction = Action<'increment' | 'decrement'>;
type UpdateCounterAction = Action<'update', number | string>;
```
Why do we get `type CounterAction = never`?

I get now distributive condition for `UpdateCounterAction` and why we need it for this part.

Comment: Here's a SO answer which does a decent job of explaining it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65492934/264794. And here's a link to a github discussion on the behavior: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182

Comment: It work without square brackets.

Comment: @jcalz checkout edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) where the type being checked (to the left of `extends`) is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, it becomes a [*distributive* conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  So in

```
type GetTestDist<T = never> = T extends never ? string : number;
type GetTestNonDist<T = never> = [T] extends [never] ? string : number;
```

`GetTestDist<T>` is a distributive conditional type because `T` is a generic type parameter, while `GetTestNonDist<T>` is not because `[T]` is not a generic type parameter.

Yes, `[T]` *involves* the generic type parameter `T`, but it is not a type parameter itself.  Sometimes people will say that the `T` in `T extends never ? ⋯ : ⋯` is a *bare* type parameter or a *naked* type parameter, as opposed to the `T` in `[T] extends [never] ? ⋯ : ⋯` which is, let's say, "clothed".

So a conditional type where the type being checked is a naked type parameter is a distributive conditional type. But what does that mean?

---

When a type function `F<T>` is a distributive conditional type, the operation [*distributes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`, meaning that it acts on each union member *individually* and joins the result back into a union.  So, for example, `F<A | B | C>` will evaluate to the same as `F<A> | F<B> | F<C>`.

Furthermore, [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is considered to be **the empty union**, so `F<never>` will always be `never` no matter what. (see [the relevant comment on microsoft/TypeScript#23182](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379094672) for an authoritative source).

This treatment of `never` might be confusing but it is consistent.  The `never` type gets absorbed into unions: that is, `X | never` is reduced to `X` no matter what `X` is.  (If you have a value `x` of type `X | never` then `x` is either of type `X` or of type `never`, but there are no values of type `never`, so `x` *must* be of type `X`.  So all values assignable to `X | never` must be assignable to `X`, and the type checker observes this by absorbing `never` into unions.  See [Why is never assignable to every type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53540282/2887218) for more information.)  You can think of `never` as [the identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) of the union operation.

So if `X | never` is equivalent to `never`, then `F<X>` and `F<X | never>` are the same.  If `F<T>` is distributive, then `F<X | never>` is equivalent to `F<X> | F<never>`.  That implies `F<X>` is the same as `F<X> | F<never>` for all `X`.  The easiest way for that to be true is if `F<never>` is just `never`.

(By analogy, imagine you have a mathematical function () which is distributive over *addition*, so that () + () = (+).  Addition has an identity element: 0, because +0 = .  That implies (0) must be 0, because () + (0) = (+0) = ().  0 is "the empty sum", and `never` is "the empty union".)

---

Often distributive behavior is desired, but sometimes it's not.  The way to turn that behavior off is therefore to "clothe" both the naked type parameter and the type you're checking against with some *covariant* type function `C<T>`.  (See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more information about variance).

```
type Distrib<T> = T extends U ? X : Y
type NonDistrib<T> = C<T> extends C<U> ? X : Y
```

You need to do it to both sides of `extends` so that you're doing the same check (if `C<T>` is covariant in `T` then `C<A> extends C<B>` implies `A extends B`). Any covariant "clothing" will suffice here.

But if you're looking for the, uh, "skimpiest" clothing so that you can save as many keystrokes as possible, then you should use `[T]`.  For better or worse, TypeScript considers array types as covariant (see [Why are TypeScript arrays covariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60905518/2887218) ), and a one-element [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) is an array type.  There's nothing more "correct" about using `[T]` over any other covariant type function, it's just the most expedient.

And therefore it is usually recommended that if you want to turn off distribution over unions in a conditional type, you wrap both sides of the `extends` with `[`⋯`]`:

```
type Distrib<T> = T extends U ? X : Y
type NonDistrib<T> = [T] extends [U] ? X : Y
```